# Whitelisting sysctl parameters for helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sysctl

I have a helm chart that deploys an app but also needs to reconfigure some sysctl parameters in order to run properly. When I install the helm chart and run `kubectl describe pod/pod_name` on the pod that was deployed, I get `forbidden sysctl: "kernel.sem" not whitelisted`. I have added a podsecuritypolicy like so but with no such luck.

```
apiVersion:policy/v1beta1
kind:PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
 name: policy
spec:
  allowedUnsafeSysctls:
    - kernel.sem
    - kernel.shmmax
    - kernel.shmall
    - fs.mqueue.msg_max
 seLinux:
   rule: 'RunAsAny'
 runAsUser:
   rule: 'RunAsAny'
 supplementalGroups:
   rule: 'RunAsAny'
 fsGroup:
   rule:'RunAsAny'
```

---UPDATE---
I also try to set the kubelet parameters via a config file in order to allow-unsafe-ctls but I get an error no kind "KubeletConfiguration" is registered for version "kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1".
Here's the configuration file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
allowedUnsafeSysctls:
 - "kernel.sem"
 - "kernel.shmmax"
 - "kernel.shmall"
 - "fs.mqueue.msg_max"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `kernel.sem` sysctl is considered as *unsafe* sysctl, therefore is disabled by default (only *safe* sysctls are enabled by default). You can allow one or more *unsafe* sysctls on a node-by-node basics, to do so you need to add `--allowed-unsafe-sysctls` flag to the `kubelet`.
Look at ["Enabling Unsafe Sysctls"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#enabling-unsafe-sysctls)

---

I've created simple example to illustrate you how it works.

First I added `--allowed-unsafe-sysctls` flag to the `kubelet`.
In my case I use `kubeadm`, so I need to add this flag to
`/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` file:

```
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --allowed-unsafe-sysctls=kernel.sem"
...
```

**NOTE:** You have to add this flag on **every** node you want to run Pod with `kernel.sem` enabled.

Then I reloaded systemd manager configuration and restarted `kubelet` using below command:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet
```

Next I created a simple `Pod` using this manifest file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: web
  name: web
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.sem
      value: "250 32000 100 128"
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: web
```

Finally we can check if it works correctly:

```
# sysctl -a | grep "kernel.sem"
kernel.sem = 32000      1024000000      500     32000 // on the worker node
# kubectl get pod
NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web    1/1     Running   0          110s
# kubectl exec -it web -- bash
root@web:/# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
250     32000   100     128 // inside the Pod
```

Your `PodSecurityPolicy` doesn't work as expected, because of as you can see in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#podsecuritypolicy):

> Warning: If you allow unsafe sysctls via the allowedUnsafeSysctls field in a PodSecurityPolicy, any pod using such a sysctl will fail to start if the sysctl is not allowed via the --allowed-unsafe-sysctls kubelet flag as well on that node.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use a config file to set allow this behavior to happen via https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ but I was getting this error: no kind "KubeletConfiguration" is registered for version kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1   I want to be able to set these permissions via a file so that if I move the helm chart to another machine; all of the configurations will be included in the file and therefore little would need to be done to make the application work properly.

Comment: Do you use `kubeadm` ?
Can you provide more information about your config file and how you pass this config file to `kubelet` ?

Comment: I've included the config file in my answer and I use the command ```kublet --config filename.yml```

Comment: @Eddie `fsq.mqueue.msg_max` doesn't exist, use `fs.mqueue.msg_max` instead and pass absolute path to `filename.yml` config.
Do you use `kubeadm` or something else ? I need this information to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yeah I meant to use "fs.mqueue.msg.max", just a typo. Also I get this error when I try to install the helm chart by running ```helm install random_name name_of_chart```, not with the kubelet command. I'm not working directly with kubernetes; I'm working with helm which creates kubernetes objects, so I'm trying to limit the amount of work I have to do on the command line so that the helm chart is functional without having to tamper with kubernetes directly.

Comment: Your `KubeletConfiguration` is correct but I still don't understand how you pass this config to `kubelet`.
What do you mean by `I get this error when I try to install the helm chart by running helm install random_name name_of_chart, not with the kubelet command.` ?
How did you configure `kubelet` to use this `KubeletConfiguration` config ?

Comment: When I created this file, I didn't use any kubelet commands to make sure the configurations worked. I placed the file in the templates directory of my helm chart and tried to install the helm chart with ```helm install random_name name_of_chart.``` Helm charts are used to configure kubernetes objects, so I'm trying to put all of my configurations inside the helm chart itself so that if I need to move around the helm chart, I can move it around with all of the configurations as well. I'm not trying to manually do anything with any kube commands since helm is supposed to manage that for me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to update `kubelet` configuration using Helm chart. 
I'm afraid that is not possible because `kubelet` is  a "node agent" that runs on each node as a service.
The `kubelet` doesn't work in `Pod` and `KubeletConfiguration` isn't Kubernetes object like a `Pod` or `Deployment`.

Comment: Oh, I understand, so I can't automatically change kubelet with the helm chart because I'm not creating a kubernetes object; I have to change the node itself.

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to configure `kubelet` service working on your nodes.

Comment: @Eddie If my answer was helpful to you please consider accepting the answer or vote on it. That way it would be more clear and visible for the rest of the community.

Comment: Please consider to read about Kubelet Dynamic Configuration feature: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/  It's still hardly possible to do that using helm.